# Como puedo llamar un método a la clase principal?

Tags: java

Mi problemas es que estoy intentado llamar un método de un clase a la clase principal, pero cada vez que intento crear un objeto para poder llamar al método, me tirar a error y no puedo hacerlo.
Quiero saber cuál es el error que estoy cometiendo. 
Aqui el codigo de la clase `Principal`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nombre, apellido;
    int edad;
    char sexo;

    System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre:");
    nombre = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese apellido");
    apellido = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese edad");
    edad = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingrese su genero");
    sexo = sc.next().charAt(0);

    Persona datos = new Persona(); // Aqui es el error//
    datos.mostrarDatos();
  }
}
```

Y aqui la clase `Persona`

```
public class Persona {
  public String nombre;
  public String apellido;
  public int edad;
  public char sexo;

  public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
  }

  public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
  }

  public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
  }

  public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
  }

  public int getEdad() {
    return edad;
  }

  public void setEdad(int edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
  }

  public char getSexo() {
    return sexo;
  }

  public void setSexo(char sexo) {
    this.sexo = sexo;
  }

  public Persona(String nombre, String apellido, int edad, char sexo) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.sexo = sexo;
  }

  public void mostrarDatos(){
    System.out.println("Su nombre es:"+nombre);
    System.out.println("Su apellido es:"+apellido);
    System.out.println("Su edad es:"+edad);
    System.out.println("Su genero es:"+sexo);
  }
}
```

El error dice:

```
constructor Persona in class Persona cannot be applied to given types;
required:String,String,int,char
found: no arguments
reason:actual and formal argument lists differ length
```

Comment: Te aconsejo que también escribas el código de la clase Persona. ¿Has importado la clase externa a la clase Principal donde éstas? Por ejemplo: import Persona;

Comment: Cual es el error que sale?

Comment: Listo, pude escribir la clase Persona

Comment: Tienes que pasar los parámetros al constructor cuando instancias `Persona`: `Persona datos = new Persona(nombre, apellido, edad, sexo);`

Comment: Gracias, el código funciona correctamente.